# Install Asus AC-53 Wireless Adapter

Tags: wireless, networking

Just installed Ubuntu alongside Windows.  Unfortunately, I require an Asus AC-53 USB wireless adapter to connect to my home network.

How can I get this adapter to work with Ubuntu?  I haven't yet been able to find any relevant documentation that would help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The packaging claimed that this adapter is Mac OS and Linux compatible but only windows compatible drivers are included in the support CD and the device support page , as i checked here :

> http://www.asus.com/Networking/USBAC53/

But as i think the chipset is in Broadcom wirelesses list, so just plug in your device to your computer and follow this instruction :

> [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx)

Comment: Please check here: wikidevi.com/wiki/ASUS_USB-AC53 It says, "Probable Linux driver none" You could try ndiswrapper.