# ASUS USB-AC53 Ubuntu 14.04 won't connect, stalled out from prior answer

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, usb, asus

[Question/Answer from earlier this year on getting ASUS USB-AC53 network adapter running in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/408900/install-correct-drivers-for-asus-usb-ac53-wifi-adapter?newreg=9fa9a2a8639c4d8ab8a66dbf52ec6e91)

Where I am stalling out is that after using ButtersB's instructions Ubuntu is recognizing the driver and seeing my wireless network, but cannot seem to authenticate the WPA2-PSK [AES] security passcode.  I believe I have the network connection settings set properly, and I definitely have the password and security type set properly, but it keeps asking me to re-enter the password rather than completing the connection.  I tried to participate in that original thread, but I'm new here so of course I screwed that up (apologies for that).

That thread here is really the most useful thing I was able to find via Google on the topic so far.  There is another top Google result for a link at this site [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407179/install-asus-ac-53-wireless-adapter) but those instructions for installing based on the chipset look like they're for PCI network adapters rather than USB, not the least of which as the ID's don't seem to match up from what I can see although if there's something I'm missing about that link I'd be happy to try things people thought might work.

If you check the top user reviews on the [Amazon page for this product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00BTWJAAE) you'll see an Asus rep state that they are not planning on releasing a native Linux driver (assuming that information is still accurate, and in spite of the fact that they announced support for Linux right on the box) and they're blaming Broadcom.

So I come hat in hand to see if there is any hope.  Thanks much for any information/advice.

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior. I'm able to install the bcmwlhigh5.inf drivers via ndiswrapper, the device is recognized,  and a wireless interface is added. However, when I attempt to connect to my network, it fails during "4-way-handshake" with an error indicating there was an authentication timeout.

Comment: So I was able to get it working! I'm not sure how, but I think it has something to do with the settings on my access point. I have an ASUS RT-AC66U. I was able to get a connection by creating an additional "guest" network with its own SSID. At first, I left the network open and attempted to connect. It worked! So, then I added WPA2-Personal authentication and using the same key as my primary network. That worked too! Unfortunately I cannot test my bandwidth because speedtest.net seems to crash my connection, but I can tell from simple web browsing that it has improved my speed magnificently.